# Google Sheets array formula help needed

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, rounding, nested-if

I am new to Google Sheets and am running into some trouble trying to figure out who to create a formula using ARRAYFORMULA, IF, AND..

I have a sheet that is used to create an inventory needed list for our satellite facility.
I have the following formula that works fine for individual cells but I am have difficulty getting a grasp on how to convert this into an ARRAYFORMULA. I am using ARRAYFORMULA in other cells but with this in having multiple IF and AND, I'm stumped. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
=if(Isblank(N2),If(And(L2>=1,O2=""),Roundup(L2/C2), If(And(L2>=1,O2="Pallet"),"Pallet",If(L2<1,Roundup(L2/C2)))),"BO")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, data, data types or layout; and we don't know your overall end goal. Please consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it) so that we can see in context what the individual format is doing. That will be the most efficient way for the volunteer contributors here to suggest an array alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. you need to use multiplication:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(N2:N),
 IF((L2:L>=1)*(O2:O=""),       ROUNDUP(L2:L/C2:C), 
 IF((L2:L>=1)*(O2:O="Pallet"), "Pallet", 
 IF( L2:L< 1,                  ROUNDUP(L2:L/C2:C)))), "BO"))
```

Comment: Player0,Thank you for your assistance, worked just as I was wanting.